# Converting string into char

Tags: c++, char, switch-statement

I've got a problem with converting types in C++. I've got an expression: `string wholeExpression = "44*2";` and I want to separate numbers from operators.
If it is a operator, I use this part of code:

```
    string subExpression;
    char skladnik;

subExpression = wholeExpression.substr(poczatek, lenght);
            skladnik = subExpression[0];
```

if it is a number:

```
subExpression = wholeExpression.substr(poczatek, lenght);
            skladnik = atoi(subExpression.c_str());
```

@EDIT

```
switch (skladnik)
        {


        case '+':
        case '-':
        {

            while (topOfStack > 0 && stack[topOfStack - 1] != '(')
            {
                outPut += stack[topOfStack - 1] + przecinek;
                stack.resize(topOfStack - 1);
                topOfStack--;
            }
            stack += skladnik;
            topOfStack++;
            break;
        }

        case '/':
        case '*':
        {
            while (topOfStack > 0 && (stack[topOfStack - 1] == '*' || stack[topOfStack - 1] == '/'))
            {
                outPut += stack[topOfStack - 1] + przecinek;
                stack.resize(topOfStack - 1);
                topOfStack--;
            }
            stack += skladnik;
            topOfStack++;
            break;
        }

        case '(':
        {
            stack += skladnik;
            topOfStack++;
            break;
        }
        case ')':
        {
            while (stack[topOfStack - 1] != '(')
            {
                outPut += stack[topOfStack - 1] + przecinek;
                stack.resize(topOfStack - 1);
                topOfStack--;
            }
            if (stack[topOfStack - 1] == '(')
            {
                stack.resize(topOfStack - 1);
                topOfStack--;
            }
            break;
        }

        default:
        {
            outPut += to_string(skladnik) + przecinek;
            break;
        }
        }


    }
```

But suddenly I've got problem with a numbers from 40 to 43 and 45 and 47 -> which are operators (in ASCII code). They are probably interpret by the switch not as numbers but as oparators. Another numbers work perfectly. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post the actual `switch` instead of this? It would be much easier to see your implementation instead of your pseudocode.

Comment: I thought that u will say it's tl;dr. That's why i tried to shorter it

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: You need to keep two different variables. It's false economy to try to use the same variable for two different things.

Comment: @Mikkey I don't see a single `isdigit()` in your entire program.  That leads me to believe you're going about this all wrong.  The intuitive way to go about this is to 1) detect that you're at the start of a number by calling `isdigit`, and if you are, start building a valid number until the character encountered isn't a digit.  You seem to have just coded something "adhoc" without any real thought to it or at the very least, a plan laid out on paper.

Comment: The most valuable answer of all these was written by  @Mark Ransom. It was all I needed to fix my code, instead of criticising me for (as you claimed, not using DEBUGGER), which i accucaly use for more than 2hours ;)

Comment: @Mark Ransom, change your comment to answer, I will accept it in order to close question

Comment: @Mikkey -- *The most valuable answer of all these* --  Please learn how stack overflow's comment section works.  This is the *comment* section.  The *comment* section is for commenting on the code and question you posted.  It isn't meant to be the answer section.  You received exactly 2 answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using your variable `skladnik` in two different ways. In one code path it refers to a decoded integer, in the second code path it refers to a character. Once you've conflated the meaning like this, there's no way to tell once you're at the `switch` which meaning it has.

You should use two different variables, one for decoded numbers and one for operator characters. Then there will be *no* confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You've answered your own question. The `char` for the number 40 doesn't exist. It's two `char` variables: 4 and 0. Because you are putting an `int` into a `char` with atoi, it is going to use the ASCII code. Without knowing the value of `lenght`, it's hard to say that this is indeed your problem, but here are two possible solutions:

1. Don't use `atoi` upfront. Instead interpret each number `char` into an actual integer after your switch statement (4 and 0 would be
   `atoi('4') * 10 + atoi('0')`)
2. use an `int` or`long` or `double` variable to hold your numbers.